# Width not getting apply for IE Compatibility modes

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Width not getting apply for IE Compatibility modes when i using following css

```
.multipleShipmentsGrid
{
    border-color:#949EAA;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    width:80%!important;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Its works fine if i apply width 80% in vb.net code side,

Comment: What do you mean by "in vb.net code side"?

Comment: Please post a live example on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are `display:inline-block;` you should specify `_display:inline;` for IE7/compat mode to set width. Setting `zoom:1;` may also help.
There may be a problem with width of container element so 80% width can't be set for your element.

Without live example on http://jsfiddle.net it is hard to tell the cause of your issue.